# Copy headers of grouped data to the rows below, through formulas or Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to have the First line of a grouped transaction in Excel copied down to the other lines. See example below, I need this persons name in cell B4 copied into Cell A6 to be able to pivot all this data, but need it done for each grouping and I am trying to avoid a manual copy/paste.

[image]

Since the data comes in a blue text I tried creating formulas for that. I have also tried copy in blanks but since the data is all group I can not get it to select the correct data.

Comment: In A6 `=IF(B5="Card#", B4, "")` and fill down

Comment: Perfect thank you